# Should I add high school entry to careers profile?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Stack Overflow Careers tells me that my profile is incomplete (65%) and requests from me to:

```
Enter a degree or institution for each education entry
Enter a valid time frame for each education entry
```

to improve my profile (and I guess to make profile completion percentage higher).

I don't have ambitions to study at university later and I'm currently in high school. I have checked option: `I am currently a student`.

The question is - should I add high school entry to careers profile or should I uncheck `I am currently a student` to make my profile more complete?

Comment: I would only add education that is related to your (future) field of work. For most people highschool doesn't apply, but it might in your case. E.g. in some countries there are different 'levels' in highschool, those might positively reflect intelligence on your profile/resume. In any case I would not uncheck the student box. That is crucial information for potential employers

Comment: You're currently a student, so I'd encourage you to indicate that (and only that - if you're < 18 they can infer your schooling status).   But, you'll also encounter a lot of positions that would prefer that you had that bachelor's degree as well.

Comment: Not unchecking I'm a student leaves my profile 'not unlocked' and without access to "additional Careers features".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to put this high school education entry in my profile. At least someone will know when I actually finish high school, because of visible time frame.